# What's a clean way to pass back groups of class instances without creating additional 'transaction' classes?

Tags: c#

To explain, every method in an API has to return an instance of a Result class along with any other objects passed back.

If I have two classes I want to pass back as single items and Lists:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public class Bar
{
}
```

That would mean I need four transaction classes to pass back:

```
public class Result
{
}

public class ApiFoo
{
    public Result Result;
    public Foo Foo;
}

public class ApiFooList
{
    public Result Result;
    public List<Foo> FooList;
}

public class ApiBar
{
    public Result Result;
    public Bar Bar;
}

public class ApiBarList
{
    public Result Result;
    public List<Bar> BarList;
}
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to pass back the correct collections than this.

Can anyone advise a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "transaction classes"? Which framework(s) / libraries are you targetting?

Comment: There is no description in the question on how to re-arrange the code to **make it better**. Question is (IMO) unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the question as I read it, which isn't with too much confidence I'll admit, generics might help. You can either make one class that can encapsulate all types, like:

```
class ResultWrapper<T>
{
    public Result Result;
    public T Value;
}
```

Then you can just:

```
return new ResultWrapper<Foo>();
return new ResultWrapper<Bar>();
```

Or:

```
return new ResultWrapper<List<Foo>>();
return new ResultWrapper<IEnumerable<Bar>>();
```

Or if you need to distinguish between lists and single items from a different view point you can add:

```
class ResultListWrapper<T>
{
    public Result Result;
    public List<T> Values;
}

return new ResultListWrapper<Foo>();
```

Taking this a little further, you haven't fleshed out the `Result` class much, but you could always apply the generics to that class:

```
class Result<T>
{
    // Existing Result members.
    public T Value;
}
```

Generics itself is also an important topic when developing in C#, it is used all over the place. Please consult the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Thanks. Yes your interpretation is correct. Will the intellisense give a clear indication of what is being passes back?

Comment: @user2078938 IntelliSense has great support for it, but I feel this is a bit of an XY Problem. I don't know what the underlying problem is that this solution is trying to solve, but this solution feels a little clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Generic` feature for this. You can do the below :

```
public class SR<T>
    {
        public T Result { get; set; }
        public T GetResult()
         {
            return Result;
         }
    }


 var result = new SR<Bar>(); or  var result = new SR<List<Bar>>();
```